# Calendar that is able to send invites from different email adresses

Tags: email, calendar, google-calendar

I am looking for a calendar app for mac, where I can choose email address that is used for sending invitations. By default, ical sends invitations with email account that is "hosting" the calendar.

For example, I import my business email into Gmail account, then I add this business email into System Preferences -> Internet Accounts. I create a new calendar in my Gmail account and add this calendar into iCal. If I send an invite in iCal, invitation is sent by default gmail account and I don't have any option to change that.

Comment: Please add the additional info to this question instead of linking to a different site.  This ensures that all important info is self-contained in the question and is available for searching.  See [this post](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/a/2181/88313) for important info that should be followed when asking for a software recommendation. - From Review

Comment: @fsb Sorry, I updated my question and described this use case.